# Siamese Network in TensorFlow employing Triplet Loss

Tags: tensorflow, cosine-distance, loss, siamese-networks, custom-layer

I am constructing a siamese network using tensorflow which uses triplet loss.
My inputs are of shape (100,100,1) and I have made a CNN embed_model to so that the output is a tensor with 50 points.
Now I have to make a custom Siamese Network, which I have done using this code:

```
class SiameseModel(tf.keras.models.Model):
    def __init__(self, embed_model, alpha=0.5):
        super().__init__()
        self.embed_model = embed_model
        self.alpha = alpha
        self.loss_tracker = tf.keras.metrics.Mean(name="loss")

    def call(self, inputs):
        return self.embed_model(inputs)

    def _compute_loss(self, data):
        anchor, positive, negative = data
        anchor_embedding = self.embed_model(anchor)
        positive_embedding = self.embed_model(positive)
        negative_embedding = self.embed_model(negative)
        
        dp = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(anchor_embedding - positive_embedding), axis=-1)
        dn = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(anchor_embedding - negative_embedding), axis=-1)
        del anchor_embedding,positive_embedding,negative_embedding
        return tf.maximum(dp - dn + self.alpha, 0.0)

    def train_step(self, data):
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            loss = self._compute_loss(data)

        gradients = tape.gradient(loss, self.embed_model.trainable_weights)
        self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, self.embed_model.trainable_weights))

        self.loss_tracker.update_state(loss)
        return {"loss": self.loss_tracker.result()}

    def test_step(self, data):
        loss = self._compute_loss(data)
        self.loss_tracker.update_state(loss)
        return {"loss": self.loss_tracker.result()}

    @property
    def metrics(self):
        return [self.loss_tracker]

siamese_model = SiameseModel(embed_model)
```

The problem I face is INCREASING LOSS IN SUCCESSIVE EPOCHS and I have tried learning rate 0.0001 but even that is not helping.

I would really appreciate it if someone can tell me where I am going wrong, I have checked several resource but they are not working on my code.

[reference notebook](https://www.kaggle.com/code/adveatprasadkarnik/siamese-network-for-signature-detection)

I have even tried the following:

Different Model structures

Different learning rate values

None of these help change the outcome

Comment: Can you also track the $l_2$-distance between (anchor, positive) and (anchor, negative) during training?